# ¿como puedo corregir error de borrado logico en laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, blade

estoy desarrollando un sistema en laravel y tengo un error cuando hago es listado de todo el arreglo que mando, listadome normal, pero cuando estoy haciendo el borrado lógico y me da esta error, no reconoce ya la variable de ese elemento borrado, pero es como volviera a preguntar por ese objeto borrado.

Poniendo un `dd($archivosList);` en el **index** del controller me permite ver el arreglo que estoy mandando

**ArchivoController.php**

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Services\SessionService;
use App\Http\Services\ArchivoService;
use App\Http\Services\PalabraService;
use App\Http\Services\PalabraArchivoService;
use App\Http\Services\CriterioService;

class ArchivoController extends Controller
{
    protected $archivoService;
    protected $palabraService;
    protected $palabraArchivoService;
    protected $criterioService;


 public function __construct(ArchivoService $archivoService, PalabraArchivoService $palabraArchivoService, PalabraService $palabraService, CriterioService $criterioService ) {
        $this->archivoService = $archivoService;
        $this->palabraArchivoService = $palabraArchivoService;
        $this->palabraService = $palabraService;
        $this->criterioService=$criterioService;
 }

 public function index(Request $request,$idPalabra) {

        $recurso = SessionService::recursoPath($request->getPathInfo());

        $archivosList = $this->archivoService->listarArchivosDePalabra($idPalabra);
        dd($archivosList);
        $criteriosList = $this->criterioService->listarCriterios();
        $palabra = $this->palabraService->obtenerPalabra(['id' => $idPalabra]);
        return view('archivo.index', [
            'archivosList' => $archivosList,
            'criteriosList' => $criteriosList,
            'recurso' => $recurso,
            'palabra' => $palabra,

  ]);
 }

 public function form(Request $request) {
  return response()->json($this->archivoService->obtenerArchivo($request->all()));
 }

 public function save(Request $request) {
        dd($request);

        return response()->json($this->archivoService->guardarArchivo($request->all()));
 }

 public function delete(Request $request) {
  return response()->json($this->archivoService->eliminarArchivo($request->all()));
 }


}
```

**ArchivoService.php**

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Services;

class ArchivoService extends GuzzleHttpRequestService {

 private function recursoApi($archivoPalabra = false) {
        return config('app.recurso_archivo'). ($archivoPalabra ? '/archivoPalabra' : '');
        //return config( $archivoPalabra ? '/archivoPalabra' : 'app.recurso_archivo');
 }

    public function listarArchivosDePalabra($idPalabra){
  return $this->get($this->recursoApi(true),$idPalabra);
 }

 public function obtenerArchivo($params) {
  return $this->get($this->recursoApi(), $params['id']);
    }

    public function listarArchivos(){
        return $this->get($this->recursoApi());
 }

 public function guardarArchivo($params) {
  if(empty($params['id'])) {
   $params['usuarioRegistro'] = $this->getUsuario();
   $resultado = $this->post($this->recursoApi(), $params);
  } else {
   $params['usuarioModificacion'] = $this->getUsuario();
   $resultado = $this->put($this->recursoApi(), $params, $params['id']);
  }
  return $resultado;
 }

 public function eliminarArchivo($params) {
  $params['activo'] = false;
  $params['usuarioModificacion'] = $this->getUsuario();
        $resultado = $this->put($this->recursoApi(), $params, $params['id']);
        return $resultado;
 }

}
```

antes de borrar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y despues del borrado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

En un principio parece que el problema reside en lo que te esta devolviendo la API a la que envías el PUT. Deberías hacer un dd de la respuesta en lugar de enviarla y ver que nos devuelve.